# How to do custom page tracking with Facebook pixel for a single page application?

Tags: reactjs, facebook, create-react-app, facebook-pixel

I'm developing a single page application on React using '[create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)'. I'd like to use Facebook Pixel for retargeting and creating custom audiences on Facebook.

Example:

Whenever a user visits /pricing I want to add `ReactPixel.track('viewPricing')`. Whenever a user visits /checkout I want to add `ReactPixel.track('viewCheckout')`.

Since it's a single page application all my events are firing at once, which, I guess, makes sense.

How do you work with custom page tracking and Facebook pixel for a single page application?

Comment: I'm using this package for the actual pixel implementation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-pixel

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing. First, do `npm install react-facebook-pixel`. Wherever you want to include FB tracking do the following:

```
import ReactPixel from 'react-facebook-pixel';

const options = {
  autoConfig: true,     // set pixel's autoConfig
  debug: false,         // enable logs
};

ReactPixel.init('Your-Pixel-Code', options);
```

This will fire a 'ViewPage'. Now, if you want to include a CustomEvent, just add an onClick to the links leading into your page:

```
<Button onClick={() => { ReactPixel.track('clickContact') }} variant="contained" color="primary" href="/contact/" >
```

That was the easiest way I could find.